# How to paste and read text table with quotes etc in R terminal

Tags: r

I have following text table which I have copied and want to paste in read.table command to create a data.frame. I type:

```
read.table(header=T, text="<enter>
```

Then I paste following in the terminal:

```
"col a"  "col b"
<.1   25
.1-1   26
1-5   35
5-10  45
10-15 55  
>15 95
```

Finally, I enter:

```
")<enter>
```

However, it does not work due to presence of quotes in column headers. How can this be corrected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either use `'` as outer quotation mark or escape the inner ones by using `\"`?

Comment: Great. I checked I could also use text=' "col a"  "col b" ...  ') . Thanks. I think it may a useful point for others also. If you enter this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work when using `read.table(stdin(), header=TRUE)`.

Comment: stdin() function is new to me. It works and I do not need to bother which quotes are there. Thanks.

Comment: @Pascal: Add stdin() solution as an answer. It will help many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `'` as outer quotation mark or escape the inner ones by using `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using `stdin()` inside `read.table`:

```
read.table(stdin(), header = TRUE)
```